# Laravel Get products from multiple taxonomies

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have 3 tables, products, taxonomies and product_taxonomy. The 3rd table is a pivot table that contains product_id and taxonomy_id, meaning that product and taxonomy are many to many relationship. Given a list of taxonomy ids, how can I get all the products that belong to these taxonomies? NOTE: I want to have the products result set being able to paginated or order by maybe it's price or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `many-to-many` relationship and that requires relationship methods like:

```
// Product Model
public function taxonomies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Taxonomy');
}

// Taxonomy Model
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
}
```

The query:

```
$listOfTaxonomyIds = [1,2,3];
$products = Product::whereHas('taxonomies', function($query) use ($listOfTaxonomyIds){
    $query->whereIn('taxonomy_id', $listOfTaxonomyIds);
})->get();
```

Comment: Perfect! Already setup the many to many relationship, just didn't know how to write the query...